# What are the expected measurement results in the diagram below?

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics

[image: scheme]

I ask you to give a mathematical solution to this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measurement result will always be $0$, assuming measurement in the standard basis. To see this, note that $HZH=X$ and that $X^2=I$. Thus the state just before measurement is $|0\rangle$.